# ec2: elb-create-lb-listeners fails

Tags: amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools, amazon-elb

Has anyone gotten amazon's elastic load balancing command: elb-create-lb-listeners to work?

Is this the right site for ec2 questions: would serverfault be better? Amazon's forums seem slow...

I get:

```
PROMPT:~ acct$ elb-create-lb-listeners <MYLBNAME> --listener "protocol=http,lb-port=80,instance-port=80"
Unable to find a $JAVA_HOME at "/usr", continuing with system-provided Java...
elb-create-lb-listeners:  Malformed input-Unknown command: 'CreateLoadBalancerListeners'.
Use '--help' to see a list of valid commands.
```

...sup with that? Do I need to download something else? My ELB cli is 1.0.10.0, and AWS_ELB_HOME is set correctly.

thanks!
Colin

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you're running the latest version and that command should work.

I'd really fix your `$JAVA_HOME` environment. That can screw things up. Also, did you make sure `$AWS_ELB_HOME` and `$AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE` are set in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this was long long back. But here's the solution:

1. Download Elastic Load Balancing API Tool from http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/2536 and unzip it.
2. Set the path as below:
   export AWS_ELB_HOME=/root/james/ElasticLoadBalancing-1.0.15.1/
   export PATH=$PATH:$AWS_ELB_HOME/bin
3. Set JAVA_HOME path as below:
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_02/
4. Place your certification and private keys to some folder and point to it as below:
   export EC2_CERT=/root/key/certfilename.pem
   export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=/root/key/pkfilename.pem

Now elb-create-lb would work :)